# How to load different versions of a package dynamically in a Genie webservice?

Tags: git, julia

I'm currently working with Julia and Genie in a production environment and need to improve our REST API.

We have an API on a server that listens to incoming solve requests from different client servers, solves them (using a Julia package with our code on a Git repository, we'll call it `CustomPkg`) and send back the result to the calling server. This works fine, but now instead of just using always the master branch of `CustomPkg` we want the API to be able to use different versions of `CustomPkg` corresponding to different branches.

So, our `routes.jl` file that contained only one route that executed the code from `CustomPkg` must now have a parameter `branch` that executes the code from `CustomPkg#branch`.

All my attempts using `Revise` or adding/developing the package on different branches were unsuccessful, did any of you ever had to treat this case ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot,

Take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there may be a way to get this working, this would probably not a good and stable solution.
Git branches are not intended to contain different programs / business logics which are called conditionally.

A better solution would be to create a separate package for each branch (maybe with a common base package) or to make one package version where the outcome is determined by input parameters (as replacement for the info which branch to take).

Comment: The issue I have is that the package I'm developing is intended to be a module of our main software. For the software we use this git branches to test new functionalities and then merge them with the master branch. This software calls `CustomPkg` via its API by passing the problem data in a POST request.
Let's say the input format changes : we have to modify both git repositories at the same time. So the first solution you mention would work, but we have to change the process of creating a new branch to test on `CustomPkg`. For the second one, how would you do that ?
Thanks ! :)

Comment: API changes in productive environments are a highly non-trivial problem ;-)
One approach would be to implement 2 versions of the API on one side (e.g. the receiver), bring the update of this program first to production and then update the API for the other program (e.g. the sender). Then, the 1st program just need to switch its API version (potentially automatically).

Comment: I can see this is a non-trivial problem after looking for answers on the web :-)
I found an (ugly) way to make it work, but it uses conditional operators to manage the GIT repository, and as you mentioned GIT is not really made for that.
I'll consider your solution and keep you updated, thanks a lot :-)